# Understanding Conservation of Momentum in Multiple Particle Systems

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, momentum, conservation-laws

I was reading from John Taylor's "Classical Mechanics", and I did not understand a certain section; namely proving the Conservation of Momentum in a multi-particle system. The book is quite cryptic. For example, to begin, the author explains the net force on particle $\alpha$ in a $N$-particle system with this equation: $$\mathbf{F_{\alpha}}=\sum_{\alpha\neq\beta} \mathbf{F_{\alpha\beta}} + \mathbf{F}^{ext}_{\alpha}$$
where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are labels for the particles equal to $1, 2,... N$. I don't understand what he means by this.

Comment: No offence intended, but your question has a certain mysterious air to it also, as in which part of his explanation do you not follow? It might involve mathjax though http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: The force on particle $\alpha$ is equal to the sum of the forces on it from the other particles, plus the external force on it.

Comment: This is a question about the interpretation of a formula. It is not about a concept of physics. The explanation could be in the text of the book.

Answer (score 0):

This represents the sum of all forces from other particles and the net external force.

Answer (score 0):

$$\mathbf{F_{\alpha}}=\sum_{\alpha\neq\beta} \mathbf{F_{\alpha\beta}} + \mathbf{F^{ext}_{\alpha}}$$

First off, my apologies if I have misunderstood you, or its too basic for you,   but just let me know.

Newton's Third Law states that when you get down to it, every interaction between a system of any number of particles can be split up into lots of just two particles interacting with each other.

You might say, it's possible 3 billiard balls can hit each other at exactly the same time, but that very rarely happens, even a millionth of a second can guarantee that you are dealing with two interacting particles, one interaction followed by the other.

So the same law of conservation of momentum that holds for two particles, holds for a thousand of them, as long as you take them in pairs and seperate them in time by the smallest amount you want.

So looking at the first term on the right

$$\sum_{\alpha\neq\beta} \mathbf{F_{\alpha\beta}}$$

$\alpha$  can't equal $\beta$, (a particle can't hit itself), and again sorry if this too basic for you, the $\Sigma $ is the total of **all** the "thumps" and the last term $\mathbf{F^{ext}_{\alpha}}$ allows for any external forces,  other than the ones created by the particles hitting off of each other.

The comment by knzhou explains the force on the left on particle $\alpha$ as the sum of all the thumps it's got from the other particles ( except itself) plus the external force  acting directly on it, apart again from the interactions of the particles of the system.